# What does it mean in JSON

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, json

```
{
    "messageshow": [
        {
            "message_id": "497",
            "message": "http://flur.p-sites.info/api/messages/voice/1360076234.caff",
            "message_pic": "<UIImage: 0xa29e160>",
            "uid": "44",
            "created": "4 hours ago",
            "username": "pari",
            "first_name": "pp",
            "last_name": "pp",
            "profile_pic": "http://flur.p-sites.info/api/uploads/13599968121.jpg",
            "tag_user": {
                "tags": [
                    {
                        "message": "false"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "boos_list": {
                "booslist": [
                    {
                        "message": "false"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "aplouds_list": {
                "aploudslist": [
                    {
                        "message": "false"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "total_comments": 0,
            "total_boos": 0,
            "total_applouds": 0
        },
        {
            "message_id": "496",
            "message": "http://flur.p-sites.info/api/messages/voice/1360076182.caff",
            "message_pic": "<UIImage: 0xa3b0610>",
            "uid": "44",
            "created": "4 hours ago",
            "username": "pari",
            "first_name": "pp",
            "last_name": "pp",
            "profile_pic": "http://flur.p-sites.info/api/uploads/13599968121.jpg",
            "tag_user": {
                "tags": [
                    {
                        "message": "false"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "boos_list": {
                "booslist": [
                    {
                        "message": "false"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "aplouds_list": {
                "aploudslist": [
                    {
                        "message": "false"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "total_comments": 0,
            "total_boos": 0,
            "total_applouds": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

In this `JSON` all value are coming in **""** quotes, but few `tags` are coming without any **quotes** what does it indicate ?

Comment: http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: where are the tags without quotes?

Comment: There are only values without quotes, all tags have quotes (if i haven't overlooked some)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**JSON Display value without quote it consider as Numeric value..**

**For JSON beginner :**

**JSON Syntax Rules**

JSON syntax is a subset of the JavaScript object notation syntax:

- Data is in name/value pairs
- Data is separated by commas
- Curly braces hold objects
- Square brackets hold arrays

`JSON` data is written as name/value pairs.

A name/value pair consists of a field name (in double quotes), followed by a colon, followed by a value:

```
"firstName" : "John"
```

This is simple to understand, and equals to the JavaScript statement:

```
firstName = "John"
```

**JSON values can be:**

- A number (integer or floating point)
- A string (in double quotes)
- A Boolean (true or false)
- An array (in square brackets)
- An object (in curly brackets)
- null

**JSON Objects :**

JSON objects are written inside curly brackets,

Objects can contain multiple name/values pairs:

```
{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }
```

This is also simple to understand, and equals to the JavaScript statements:

```
firstName = "John"
lastName = "Doe"
```

**JSON Arrays :**
`JSON` arrays are written inside square brackets.

An array can contain multiple objects:

```
{
"employees": [
{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, 
{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
{ "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" }
]
}
```

**In the example above**, the object `"employees"` is an array containing three objects. Each object is a record of a person (*with a first name and a last name*).

This is Basic of `JSON`

For more understanding [refere this site.](http://www.json.org/)
**Thanks**

Answer (score 1):

The tags which are without double quotes are integer values or Boolean Values or NULL.

The tags which are starting with [] square brackets are Arrays.

The tags which are starting with {} is JSON inside a attribute/value.

Comment: That is a numeric value. It is without quotes. It is 0, NOT NULL!

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the type of the value. If the value is an numerical type its ***WITHOUT*** the quotes.
If it is no numerical type it's ***WITH*** the quotes (for example `Strings`, like most in your example).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to strings JSON supports numerical values. So in this case the values without quotes are simply considered numbers.

Answer (score 0):

They are numeric values. As per the [JSON](http://www.json.org/) docs:

> A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or
>   false or null, or an object or an array. These structures can be
>   nested.